# Why would layoutIfNeeded be called upon scrolling the uitableviewcontroller?

Tags: ios, performance, uitableview, uikit, instruments

I'm trying to optimize the UITableViewController for slower devices, and after eliminating many of the reasons why a tableview might be slow, I'm still trying to figure out the last one...

[image]
This screenshot is from instruments, showing the most expensive calls, during a time where no call is made to get `heightForRowAtIndexPath` or `cellForRowAtIndexPath` (scrolling ~10px up and down repeatedly without causing any cell to go out of the table, or get rendered).

Is this normal behavior? Why would the view need relayout if the content of the page is not changing?

Comment: Just as a sanity check, would you mind pasting here your table view delegate methods?

Answer (score 2):

Every time you scroll, you change the `contentOffset`. `contentOffset` updates `bounds`, specifically its `origin`. Every `bounds` change marks receiver for layout need in next update cycle. In this case to update `frame` of floating subviews like scroll indicator, table headers and footers, ... This is totally normal behaviour and there is nothing you can do about it. Don't worry, you are redisplaying, not redrawing.

Answer (score 1):

We'd have to see some code to identify exactly why that method is being called but it could be from one of these reasons at least:

1. You have constraints that are being changed when scrolling even if you don't see it, they might be affected, maybe inside the UITableViewCell?
2. It does't have anything to do with the table view, the view just has something else to layout, maybe you made a constraint modification...
3. Your calling a method thats calls it explicitly.

Also remember this will only layout the view 'if needed'.

Comment: It's a simple tableview... No scroll related code. The only methods which are implemented are viewdidload, cell for row at index path, and height for cell at index path (+ number of rows/sections)

Comment: Are you maybe setting any of the cell's properties after they've been loaded? (e.g. download an image then show it)